# Matlab, add vector to matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to add a vector to an existing matrix.

Example:

```
matrix=[1 2 3
        4 5 6
        0 7 0]

vector = [7
          8]
```

So the target is to find the equal number of vector and matrix for example with:

```
ismember(matrix,vector)
```

After that the vector should insert into the matrix like the following:

```
matrix=[1 2 3
        4 5 6
        0 7 0
        0 8 0]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. You have a MxN matrix and you want to "insert" a vector where the first element of your vector matches a matrix entry? Waht if there is more than one match? Btw, this sounds like a XY-Problem maybe? Please clarify your question

Comment: You should show multiple input output examples if the solution below is insufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `ismember`, you can better use `find` with two output arguments:

```
>> [row, col]=find(matrix==vector(1))
row =
     3
col =
     2
```

Using Matlab's automatic matrix expansion, and assuming the vector is a column vector (you can adjust the code accordingly):

```
>> matrix(row:(row+length(vector)-1),col) = vector
matrix =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     0     7     0
     0     8     0
```

If the match is not at the edge (i.e., `row~=size(matrix,1)`), this would not work though, as the vector would override other entries.

Comment: You have a idea what i can do if the match is not at the edge? a function to insert the vector and not to override would be nice.

Comment: Maybe you should update the problem with a full set of examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MatthiasR. If this works, consider marking the answer as accepted so this question is shown as closed. Otherwise edit your question to explain why this *doesn't* answer your question.